# Convert Active Directory DistinguishedName to Domino Name

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

We are integrating our lotus notes applications with Active Directory for authentication and mailing.

Authentication works fine and once logged it return the name in the below format

```
CN=Arumugam, Barath/OU=Users/OU=Region - North America/DC=mhf/DC=mhc
```

However there is no attribute in active directory which matches the above format. The closest match is attribute called distinguishedName. It is in below format.

```
CN=Arumugam\, Barath,OU=Users,OU=Region - North America,DC=mhf,DC=mhc
```

Is there a way I can convert distinguishedName to domino names in SSJS or @formula. I am not sure how domino automatically converts to the first format after login. I hope there should be someway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Directory Assistance you can set up username mapping. See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_CONFIGURING_DIRECTORY_LOOKUPS_WHEN_DOMINO_HANDLES_AUTHENTICATION_AND_USERS_ARE_MANAGED_PRIMARILY_THROUGH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_STEPS.html

Comment: This configuration requires you to add users' Notes distinguished names to Active Directory user accounts. But in current Active Directory we dont have anything called Notes Distinguished name but still domino manages to get it somehow.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to map distinquishedName . Now it is working fine.

Comment: Little bit out of scope, but: Guys, did you manage to automate synchronization between AD<->Domino? As Tivoli Directory Integrator is entitled with Domino, I'm planning to use it to automatically sync AD and Domino Directories (AD is primary). Just would like to clarify, is anybody had such tested such deployment? ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add users and groups from AD to ACL, by replacing all commas "," in distinguishedName with "/". Of course, the name mapping option have to be set up correctly and Notes distinguished name should be mapped to the distinguishedName field in AD. In your case the notes name should looks like this:

```
CN=Arumugam Barath/OU=Users/OU=Region - North America/DC=mhf/DC=mhc
```

Domino converts the names in the AD field distinguishedName by itself. You don't need to add Notes names for AD users.

The only thing that did not work for me: if I put the user or group from AD in the Domino group, and then add the Domino group to ACL for a DB, the user from AD still does not have access to DB.