# Using Notes Address Book and Active Directory for Domino authentication concurrently

Tags: authentication, lotus-domino

We would like to allow both IBM Notes AND Active Directory authentication to be used for Domino application servers, at least for now. Employees are gradually moving from Notes to O365 (uses AD), for mail, so this will allow both methods to be used for applications in the interim. My question is a bit similar, but more specific, to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744182/convert-active-directory-distinguishedname-to-domino-name). We basically followed this [IBM technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_usingnotesdistinguishednamesinaremoteldapdirector_t.html), added the distinguished names to the AD, set up the Directory Assistance (DA), and it is working somewhat. This is what we found:

- Once logged in with the AD account, the Domino server correctly matches the AD account with the Notes account, thereby using Domino for authorization. This means that Notes groups, roles, ACLs, etc., work properly. For example, for one application, I logged in with my AD account in one browser and my Notes account in the other. After saving changes in both, I could see the changes in each browser (documents only shown based on @Username). In the back-end, all documents were updated by the same Notes user. So, two ways to authenticate to the same Notes account.
- On a production server (in same Domino domain as the Notes LDAP), logging in with the AD account forces a change password page. Note that the Notes accounts still have their passwords and password expiration policies. I acknowledge that if we remove these, it should work, but it's not something we want to do right now.
- On the production server, logging in with an AD account that is not in Domino is almost immediate. Otherwise, it can take around 10 seconds (which is unacceptable).
- When logging into another Domino server, in a different Domino domain from the LDAP, the login is still slow, as above, but no change password page appears.
- From the Domino server, we can ping the AD, and a trace shows only two hops.
- Changing the order of the AD in the DA doesn't seem to make any difference on the slowness, nor does disabling the Notes directories.

Any idea how we can concurrently use Domino and the AD to authenticate to Domino application servers? Has anybody been able to achieve this? Have you found a way to speed up the authentication process? Also, have you seen the change password page in this example, and if so, what did you do to fix it?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs help with this, we asked IBM's help, and this is the answer:

1. In order to remove the "change password" page, clear the value of the "PasswordDigest" field in the person documents.
2. To fix the speed, use custom LDAP filters, as per [this IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21211660).